# How can I embed youtube video by entering video id in input?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I want to make an input that embeds a youtube video by entering a video id. This is what I tried, but it didn't work

**HTML**

```
<form action="http://www.youtube.com/embed/">
   <input class="EnterID" type="text" id="txtSRC" />
   <input class="submitid" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SetSrc()" />
</form>

<iframe id="myIfreme" src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="yes" height="420" width="640"></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function SetSrc() {
            document.getElementById("myIfreme").src = document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Try removing the form or prevent the default submit event. You failed to tell us what happened beyond "it didn't work". Without preventing the default form submit process you almost certainly ended up on youtube due to the action of the form

Comment: You should really start adding your listeners using element.addEventListener in javascript rather than inlining them. Inline event handling is an attack vulnerability for hackers, and they won't work if you set a content-security-policy.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. You should activate your function off of form onsubmit

2. Add the event object, call `preventDefault()` on it, and then use `document.location = ...;`

   ```
        function SetSrc(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("myIfreme").src = document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
            document.location = ...;
        }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Why does action have the url to be prepended? It should be in the javascript code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function SetSrc() {
            document.getElementById("myIfreme").src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
        }

</script>
```